# Equicontinuity on a compact set

Tags: real-analysis

Let M be a compact metric space. Suppose that a family $F⊂C(X)$ is pointwise equicontinuous. Prove that $F$ is uniformly equicontinuous.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
Every function $f\in C^0(M)$ for a compact metric space $M$ is uniformly continuous.